# Extract groups separated by space

Tags: regex, preg-match

I've got following string (example):

```
Loader[data-prop data-attr="value"]
```

There can be 1 - n attributes. I want to extract every attribute. (data-prop,data-attr="value"). I tried it in many different ways, for example with `\[(?:(\S+)\s)*\]` but I didn't get it right. The expression should be written in PREG style..

Comment: Would every Loader element have the same string structure? I mean, would property and value always be sepparated by a single space?

Comment: I think [`preg_match_all('~(?:\[|(?!^)\G)\s*(\w+(?:-\w+)*)(?:="?([^"\]]*))?~', $txt, $matches)`](https://regex101.com/r/tY6rF6/1) should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest grabbing all the key-value pairs with a regex:

```
'~(?:([^][]*)\b\[|(?!^)\G)\s*(\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:=(["\'])?[^\]]*?\3)?)~'
```

(see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tY6rF6/4)) and then

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pNB8bw)

```
$re = '~(?:([^][]*)\b\[|(?!^)\G)\s*(\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:=(["\'])?[^\]]*?\3)?)~'; 
$str = "Loader[data-prop data-attr=\"value\" more-here='data' and-one-more=\"\"]"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        $arr = array_merge(array_filter($matches[$i]),$arr);
    }
}
print_r(preg_grep('~\A(?![\'"]\z)~', $arr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => data-prop
    [4] => data-attr="value"
    [5] => more-here='data'
    [6] => and-one-more=""
    [7] => Loader
)
```

Notes on the regex (it only looks too complex):

- `(?:([^][]*)\b\[|(?!^)\G)` - a boundary: we only start matching at a `[` that is preceded with a word (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) character (with `\b\[`), or right after a successful match (with `(?!^)\G`). **Also, `([^][]*)` will capture into Group 1 the part before the `[`.**
- `\s*` - matches zero or more whitespace symbols
- `(\w+(?:-\w+)*)` - captures into Group 2 "words" like "word1" or "word1-word2"..."word1-wordn"
- `(?:=(["\'])?[^\]]*?\3)?` - optional group (due to `(?:...)?`) matching

  - `=` - an equal sign
  - `(["\'])?` - Group 3 (auxiliary group to check for the value delimiter) capturing either `"`, `'` or nothing
  - `[^\]]*?` - (value) zero or more characters other than `]` as few as possible
  - `\3` - the closing `'` or `"` (the same value captured in Group 3).

Since we cannot get rid of capturing `'` or `"`, we can `preg_grep` all the elements that we are not interested in with `preg_grep('~\A(?![\'"]\z)~', $arr)` where `\A(?![\'"]\z)` matches any string that is not equal to `'` or `"`.

Comment: Thank you, but I really just need the groups as strings. My intensions is, to extract the name (Loader) as first match, and the others as following matches. I tried to achieve this here: https://regex101.com/r/pT9jS2/1 but I didn't get it right. My goal is to have the mach: 1: Loader / 2: data-prop / 3: data-attr="value"

Comment: And do it with a single `preg_match` *capturing* the key-value pairs? That is impossible with PCRE. I will update my solution acc. to the current requirements.

Comment: Sorry to still use such a hideously large regex. I hope it will work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like `[\s\[]([^\s\]]+(="[^"]+)*)+`

gives

MATCH 1: `data-prop`

MATCH 2: `data-attr="value"`